# Convert a letter into a number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am building the back end of a web application which is processing a significant portion of data and the front end developers are looking for a stable integer code to use in joining data.

The current integer values they are trying to use are surrogate keys which will change going forward leading to a number of problems. 
Each table has a alphanumeric code and I am looking for a way in which I could convert this into a stable int.

EG convert a code 'AAAA' into 1111 or MMMM into 13131313

Could anyone tell me if this is at all possible.

Thanks,

Comment: And how do you expect to distinguish 'ACAC' -> 1313 from 'MM' -> 1313 ?

Comment: select disctinct codes in a temp table, assign an int value to each code, update first table

Comment: What is the maximum width of these codes?

Comment: Make a stored procedure wich loops over the existing code, translates each character as follows: SELECT ASCII(c) – ASCII(‘A’) + 1. Then put the result in an intermediate string containing only numeric chars. Funally, using cast, put the result in the new numeric field

Comment: One-to-one conversion is possible but you need to provide specific details of the current alpha-numeric values. What letters are valid, is mixed case allowed, how long are the strings (min and max), is any portion invariant, are any other symbols allowed?

Comment: @PeterB.. `1313` is must be `acac`. Because,  code length is `4`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

McNets' comment seems to be a very good approach...

If you can be sure, that you have

- plain ASCII characters
- Not more than 4 letters

You might cast the string to `VARBINARY(4)` and cast this to `INT`:

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(StrangeCode VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @dummy VALUES
 ('AAAA'),('MMMM'),('ACAC'),('CDEF'),('ABCD');

SELECT CAST(CAST(StrangeCode AS VARBINARY(4)) AS INT)
FROM @dummy;
```

The result

```
1094795585
1296911693
1094926659
1128547654
1094861636
```

If you need bigger number, you might go up to `BIGINT`

Answer (score 1):

A way is using CTE like this:

```
;with tt(i, c1, c2) as (
    select 1, c, replace(c,char(65), 1)
    from yourTable
    union all
    select i+1, c1, c2= replace(c2,char(65+i), i+1)
    from tt
    where i < 26
)
select c1, cast(c2 as bigint) num
from tt
where i = 26;
```

Answer (score 0):

As McNets suggests, create a second table:

```
create table IntCodes (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), UserCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

insert into IntCodes (UserCode)
    select distinct UserCode
    from MyTable
```

You'll need a trigger:

```
create trigger Trg_UserCode 
on MyTable
after insert as
begin
  insert into IntCodes (UserCode)
  select i1.UserCode 
  from INSERTED i1
  where i1.UserCode not in (select ic.Usercode from IntCodes ic)
end
```

Now, as part of the query:

```
select t1.*, t2.id as IntCode
from MyTable t1
inner join IntCodes t2
on t1.UserCode = t2.UserCode
```

This means that you won't need to worry about updating the existing columns